# consume a webservice to show list xamarin forms

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, xaml, xamarin.forms

i want to show a list of expenses in xamarin(VS 2019) consuming webservice,but when running my app, it shows me an empty list but When i use breakpoint, i found that the informations are reaching in the element "content"

PS: the service is running in the postman,

ListExpenses.xaml

```
    <ListView x:Name="listexpense" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding expenseLists}" 
              HasUnevenRows="True">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell Height="150">
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                 Orientation="Horizontal">
                           <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                           <Label Text="{Binding Nature}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding AmountHT }"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding AmountReimbursed }"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding AmountExceeds }"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ExpenseReport }"/>


                            </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

ListExpenses.xaml.cs

```
     public partial class ListExpenses : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ListExpenses()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetExpense();
    }
    public async void GetExpense()
    {  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.6:3000/api/adepApi/GetExpenseReports");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://192.168.1.6:3000/api/adepApi/GetExpenses");
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        ResponseData EL = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData>(content);
        viewRapport.ItemsSource = EL.Data.expenseRLists;
    }
    class ResponseData
    {
        public ExpensRapportList Data;
    }
          private List<Expense> expenseList { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("expenses")]
    public List<Expense> expenseLists
    {
        get { return expenseList; }
        set
        {
            if (value != expenseList)
            {
                expenseList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }            
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Expense.cs

```
public class Expense{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nature { get; set; }
    public string AmountHT { get; set; }
    public string AmountReimbursed { get; set; }
    public string AmountExceeds { get; set; }
    public string ExpenseReport { get; set; }
```

}

my webService

```
[Description("Get Expenses")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetExpenses()
{
    var WorkContext = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>();
    var expenseBo = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IExpenseBo>();

    var success = true;
    var errorMessage = String.Empty;
    var successNotificationMessage = String.Empty;
    IList<ExpenseModelCustom> expenses = null;
    try
    {
        expenses=new List<ExpenseModelCustom>();
        expenses = expenseBo.GetExpenses();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        success = false;
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult
    {
        Data = new
        {
            expenses = expenses,
            Success = success,

        }
    };
}
```

Json:

```
 {"ContentEncoding": null,
  "ContentType": null,
  "Data": {
   "expenses": [
    {
        "userId": null,
        "Id": 4362,
        "Name": "fda",
        "Description": null,
        "Provider": null,
        "Nature": "Déjeuner région Parisienne",
        "AmountHT": 16.67,
        "AmountTTC": 20,
        "AmountReimbursed": 20,
        "Tva": "20 %.",
        "Remboursable": true,
        "Distance": null,
        "IsIk": false,
        "ExpenseReport": "Senda JAOUANI",
        "IsDeleted": false,
        "StatusSystemName": "Draft",
        "Status": "Draft_",
        "HasDocuments": true,
        "Devise": "€",
        "ReportStatus": "Draft",
        "AmountExceeds": false,
        "Date": "2020-03-26T15:24:22",
        "StartDate": null,
        "EndDate": null,
        "Departure": null,
        "ExpenseNatureId": null,
        "CurrencyId": null,
        "TvaId": null,
        "Quantity": null,
        "ExpenseReportId": null,
        "IsDeplacementComplementaire": null,
        "IsFromHome": null,
        "IsToHome": null,
        "Remboursabledistance": null,
        "DistanceHomeToWork": null,
        "IsAlleRetour": null,
        "MissionPlace": null,
        "IsInclud": null,
        "PhysicalEntityId": null,
        "CompanyEntity3Id": null,
        "ventilationTvaList": null,
        "InvitedInExpense": null,
        "ExternalInvitedInExpense": null,
        "documentIds": null,
        "Amount": null
    },
    {
        "userId": null,
        "Id": 4356,
        "Name": "Reprise Initialisation de Plafond",
        "Description": "Reprise Initialisation de plafond",
        "Provider": null,
        "Nature": "Petit déjeuner",
        "AmountHT": 250,
        "AmountTTC": 250,
        "AmountReimbursed": 250,
        "Tva": null,
        "Remboursable": true,
        "Distance": 100,
        "IsIk": false,
        "ExpenseReport": "Reprise Initialisation de Plafond",
        "IsDeleted": false,
        "StatusSystemName": "",
        "Status": "",
        "HasDocuments": false,
        "Devise": "€",
        "ReportStatus": "Approved",
        "AmountExceeds": false,
        "Date": "2019-11-28T00:00:00",
        "StartDate": null,
        "EndDate": null,
        "Departure": null,
        "ExpenseNatureId": null,
        "CurrencyId": null,
        "TvaId": null,
        "Quantity": null,
        "ExpenseReportId": null,
        "IsDeplacementComplementaire": null,
        "IsFromHome": null,
        "IsToHome": null,
        "Remboursabledistance": null,
        "DistanceHomeToWork": null,
        "IsAlleRetour": null,
        "MissionPlace": null,
        "IsInclud": null,
        "PhysicalEntityId": null,
        "CompanyEntity3Id": null,
        "ventilationTvaList": null,
        "InvitedInExpense": null,
        "ExternalInvitedInExpense": null,
        "documentIds": null,
        "Amount": null
       }
],
"Success": true }, "JsonRequestBehavior": 1,  "MaxJsonLength": null, "RecursionLimit": null}
```

Comment: `ListExpenses` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then in the setter of `expenseLists` has to notify that the property has changed so the binding can actually detect it. There should be loads of guids on how to do this online

Comment: @Knoop yeah i make it already !

Comment: Nice! Good luck on your project!

Comment: i didn't found the problem yet :/

Comment: is your json just ONE expense, or a list of expenses?  You are deserializing it as a SINGLE expense object.

Comment: i want to show a list not only one !!

Comment: That's not what I asked you.  Please post a sample of the json returned by your webservice and the code of your `Expense` class

Comment: Please show the updated code then. Because what you posted here absolutely does not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` (and therefor will not show the list when you update it with a value from your webservice)

Comment: if your webservice only returns ONE expense, so how do you plan on displaying a list of expenses?

Comment: when i run my webservice in postman it shows a list of expenses like what i have in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webservice returns a wrapper object that contains an array inside of it.  So you will need to deserialize the wrapper.  Using json2csharp.com will generate the classes for you

```
// assume the wrapper class is "RootObject"
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

// now your List of Expenses is a property of RootObject, let's assume
// it's called "Expenses"
listexpense.ItemsSource = data.Expenses;
```

you will also need to update the Binding paths in your XAML to match the property names of the modified Expense object

Comment: this is the error that i had:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object(e.g{"name":"value"})into type'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Expense]' because the type requires a JSON array(e.g.[1,2,3])to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array(e.g. [1,2,3])or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type(e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>)...

Comment: that tells me that your JSON is NOT an array.  I earlier asked you to post a sample of your json and you did not.

Comment: the JSON you posted bears no relation to the Expense class in your client.  Please use json2csharp.com to generate a correct class

Comment: in fact, in the web service i have many attributes, but I want to display only some, (I don't know if I answered your comment or not)

Comment: You json is a wrapper that includes an array of expenses inside of it.  None of the property names in your class match the JSON property names.  You CANNOT simply deserialize that to an array.  Use json2csharp.com as I suggested.

Comment: i have changed the property names, but i have the same problm :/

Comment: go to json2csharp.com.   Paste in your JSON.  It will create C# classes for you.  Copy those C# classes to your project.  Then do what I've shown in my answer.

Comment: @wafa Please remember to mark the helpful reply as answer, or you can also share one solution here and mark it as answer, it is beneficial to others to find this answer, thanks.